# Is there any way to customize card.io SDK?

Tags: card.io

First let me thank you for your hard work and excellent, smart sdk for credit card processing.

I arrived at a point and want to customize it for one my client needs. Is there any way to customize it? Say For example, I want to detect the card holder name, on card, adding business logo, etc?

Answer (score 2):

All available customization can be found in the well-documented header files that ship with the SDK. We don't document all the available choices in the integration page, to avoid overwhelming.

If there's something that you want that isn't available via the documented headers, feel free to drop a note to support@card.io with your feature request.